# exclude certain descendants by tag name, then grab the text

Tags: c#, html, xpath, html-agility-pack

I'm scraping some data off a webpage using HtmlAgilityPack in C#. I got the element that has all the text I want to grab but the problem is that I want to exclude certain elements, such as <big> and <style> elements. Some of the pages have <style> elements in random spots and currently HtmlAgilityPack is including the CSS rules as text.

I currently have the following code:

```
var paragraphElements = bodyElement.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name == "p" && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.InnerText)).ToList();
```

"paragraphElements" does contain all <p> elements but some of those elements contain the type of elements I don't want as children.

I tried using XPath syntax with the SelectNodes() method but the few attempts I made that I thought would work, it kept returning an empty array.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: xpath searches can definetly do this if you look into xpath a lot further you'll find the solution , I can't remember off the top of my head, but I believe that you do something like *not()  and put what to exclude in there

Comment: Please show the HTML of that page.

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

```
var bodyElement = doc.GetElementbyId("mainentrycontent").Clone();

bodyElement.SelectNodes(".//br | .//img | .//style | .//big").ToList().ForEach((e) => { e.Remove(); });
```

I'll just remove the not-wanted elements on a cloned copy boefre grabbing the inner text of the cloned element.